# How to specify JDBC setting in a struts project?

Tags: jdbc, struts, websphere, jndi, web.xml

I am trying to setup a struts project locally. One way I know to set up JDBC settings as to go to administrative console of websphere and create JDBC provider and JNDI and all. But is there any other way to do in the code itself?
There is some resource reference in web.xml. I am totally new to struts.Please help.

DataSourceAlias
javaxsql.Data...... etc etc

Comment: <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to access a database through JDBC without configuring a JNDI datasource, or do you have trouble using your existing JNDI resource? By the way JDBC and struts have nothing to do with each other, so using one will not impact how you use the other.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) I have set up the whole JDBC setting in the administrative console.. But when I am testing the connection its giveing me error: Class not found exception for the implementation class name DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource. I have set the path in environment variables of websphere for that cell. Then what is the reason for error?

Comment: Under Resources > JDBC > JDBC Providers, you have a DB2 provider configured there?

Comment: @Aarav Which version of Websphere you are using?

Comment: I am using WAS 7. I am able to set this up. But it still apperars strange to me how it has worked. I have set the environment variable for JDBC class path with "\" this slash.. which was my first mistake. But its on windows so I dont know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you configured for WAS 6.1and configuration is good you need to stop and start nodeAgents for the changes to get propagated and test the jdbc connection after restarting.....if it was WAS 8 they will be propagated automatically that means you configured improperly